# QSS properties for custom widget: How to implement hover and pressed states

Tags: qt, qt5, qpainter, qtstylesheets, qproperty

I found this example on the web on how to implement custom properties accessible from QSS for custom QWidgets: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Style_Sheets_and_Custom_Painting_Example

Does anyone know how can I implement the widget so that I can have different colors for hover or pressed states?

Current stylesheet looks like this:

```
SWidget
{
 qproperty-lineColor: yellow;
 qproperty-rectColor: red;
}
```

I want to be able to have something like this:

```
SWidget:hover
{
 qproperty-lineColor: blue;
 qproperty-rectColor: green;
}

SWidget:pressed
{
 qproperty-lineColor: orange;
 qproperty-rectColor: violet;
}
```

**Note:** I know it is possible to implement mouse events and change the colors using qproperties specific to the mouse events, for example:

```
SWidget
{
 qproperty-lineColor: yellow;
 qproperty-rectColor: red;
 qproperty-lineColor-hover: orange;
 qproperty-rectColor-hover: violet;
}
```

but I would like to be able to make it work using the original qss/css way.

Regards!

Comment: Hi, do you really want to use the qproperty system ? Because just hover/pressed change in your design can be done with pure CSS.

Comment: yes, :hover and :pressed are triggered fine for SWidget widget but only for standard properties (color, background-color, border, image, etc.). However, I need custom properties. For example I have a drawing of a few lines that I need to change in a different color on hover and I would like it done with QSS. This way widgets are way more easier to customize.

Answer (score 0):

When user hover or pressed widget, you should change some widget property. And make different QSS selector for that properties. 
After change property you should make unpolish\polish of application styles.

```
qApp->style()->unpolish( this );
qApp->style()->polish( this );
```

Where "this" current window pointer. That "magic"  code will help to have affect of appropriate QSS selector.